# Exit codes of "python setup.py install"

Tags: python, syntax, build-automation, exit-code

It appears "python setup.py install" always returns a 0 exit code, even if the script was unsuccessful (e.g. SyntaxError).

That's not so great for build automation. Is there an accepted way of detecting that it failed?

Comment: Without any example of what you are trying this on, we can't really help you.

Comment: Use any python package. Introduce an error. Run "python setup.py install". "echo $?" (on *nix). Is: 0. Should be: not-0. What's a good workaround?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps see if there's a try block masking the error.

Comment: Firstly, remove any `try` blocks in the code, like @IronMan said. Then see if the line you introduced will actually raise an error. If you are not sure, then you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62543794/edit) your questions to include it, and we can tell you.